# How to nest points (shapes) inside a circle (shape)?

Tags: graphviz, petri-net

I would love to get to:
[image]

I try variations on such graph:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=circle penwidth=2 fixedsize=true label=""]
    token [shape=point ]
    place [ xlabel="P2" _background="digraph G { e[shape=point ] }"]
}
```

testable in [this online form](http://mdaines.github.io/viz.js/form.html) resulting in:

[image]

What shall I do to place a dot (`token`) inside a circle (`place`)

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz programs generally don't like intentionally placing nodes on top of other nodes, but allow it under special circumstances - **neato -n** and **neato -n2** allow it (see the FAQ).
[image]

I added a new attribute (dotme) to this input file:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=circle penwidth=2  label=""]
    n1 [ xlabel="P1" dotme=1]
    n2 [ xlabel="P2" ]
    n3 [ xlabel="P3" dotme=1]
  
    n1 -> n2
    n1 -> n3
    n2 -> n3
}
```

then ran it through this set of Graphviz programs:

```
dot -Tdot needsadot.gv |gvpr -c -fdotMe.gvpr |neato -n2 -Tpng >needsadot.png
```

where the gvpr program dotMe.gvpr is here:

```
BEGIN {

  int nxt=0;

}
N {
  int i;
  string str1, str2;
  node_t n;

  if (hasAttr($, "dotme")){
    if (strcmp($.dotme,"1")==0){
      // create a new node and position it on top of existing node
      str1=sprintf("__dot_%d", ++nxt);
      n=node($G, str1);
      n.pos=$.pos;
      n.shape="point";
    }
  }
}
```

**dotMe.gvpr** adds a new node on top of (same **pos**) every node where dotme==1.
Convoluted, but reusable.

Comment: Wouldn't `n1 [ xlabel="P1" label="."]` do a similar thing, the dot is a bit thin, but maybe there are some possibilities to enlarge it.

Answer (score 0):

Albert's idea (using unicode symbols) works great (using point size to change the dot size):

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=circle penwidth=2  label=""]
    n1 [ xlabel="P1" label=<<font point-size="8">&#9899;</font>>]
    n2 [ xlabel="P2" ]
    n3 [ xlabel="P3" label=<<font point-size="6">&#9899;</font>>]
  
    n1 -> n2
    n1 -> n3
    n2 -> n3
}
```

gives this:
[image]